# Convert Int32 to Bool

Tags: c#

I am currently writing an app that looks at SQL Agent Jobs. I'm trying to convert [FrequencyInterva](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobschedule.frequencyinterval.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1)l property to 7 bool fields (one for each day)

I was thinking of using a case statement for every possible combination but was wondering if there is a more efficient way?

Comment: can you provide some code

Comment: Maybe something along the way [`BitConverter`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/apps/system.bitconverter_members(v=vs.85).aspx) can help?

Comment: Not really an answer, but why not just create a custom method that's like 3 lines of code that converts it for you? Probably a lot easier.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You don't need seven bool variables, but you can just define an enum with the [attribute Flags](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) with the values equals to those defined for that property. 
Then assign the [FrequencyInterval](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.agent.jobschedule.frequencyinterval.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1) property to a variable of this enum type.

```
[Flags]
public enum frequencyDaysEnum
{
    Sunday = 1,
    Monday = 2,
    Tuesday = 4,
    Wednesday = 8,
    Thursday = 16,
    Friday = 32,
    Saturday = 64,
// You can also add these but they are not necessary
//    WeekDays = 62,
//    WeekEnds = 65,
//    EveryDay = 127
}

void Main()
{
    int value = 65; // <= this is the value of your property
    frequencyDaysEnum days = (frequencyDaysEnum)value;

    if(days.HasFlag(frequencyDaysEnum.Saturday))
        Console.WriteLine("It has frequency on Saturday");

    if (days.HasFlag(frequencyDaysEnum.Sunday))
        Console.WriteLine("It has frequency on Sunday");
}
```

Comment: After reading this, the Weekdays enum referenced on that page made sense so I used that rather than writing my own. Thanks very much.